# Filament 3.2, Repeater value Not shown in edit mode

Tags: repeater, laravel-filament

I have dependent fields in the question model. when I select type the question form gets changed based on type ( int values 1,2..). The issue is it works best on the create page but when it goes to the edit page, the repeater's option values do not show. Only the select field is selected to the single choice question but values from the repeater does not gets shown, My code is below:

[image]